# Will running Apache as a Reverse Proxy to my webserver slow down the webserver requests?

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, speed, erlang

In other words, lets say I have an erlang webserver on port 8000. Now I proxy port 80 to that webserver with Apache. Am I losing a lot of benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably gaining some benefits.

You can handle 'simple' requests with apache, which will be faster.

You can add access controls, rewrite urls, and other things which apache can do for you.